# Sending data to device via MS Comm VB6

Tags: vb6

I need to send a file to some electronic device and execute it.

I couldn't find any information online regarding MS Comms and I didn't find Documentation on the Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231237(v=vs.60).aspx) any useful :

```
' Send Byte array data
MSComm1.Output = Out
```

Would be great if you guys could give me some pointers and help me to solve my problem. The problem that I am experiencing is an infinite loop at `Loop Until MSComm1.OutBufferCount = 0`, when I return "MSComm1.OutBufferCount" between Do and Loop "MSComm1.OutBufferCount" is 0 and files dont seem to be sent over to the device.

Closest function I got to at the present moment is below:

```
Function SendFile(tmp$)

    Dim temp$
    Dim hsend, bsize, LF&

    ' Open file
    Open tmp$ For Binary Access Read As #2
    ' Check size on Mscomm1 OutBuffer
    bsize = MSComm1.OutBufferSize
    ' Check file length
    LF& = LOF(2)

    ' This code makes tiny pieces of data (Buffer sized)
    ' And send's it

    Do Until EOF(2)

        If LF& - Loc(2) <= bsize Then
            bsize = LF& - Loc(2) + 1
        End If

        ' Make room for some data
        temp$ = Space$(bsize)

        ' Put the data piece in the Temp$ string
        Get #2, , temp$

        MSComm1.Output = temp$

        Do
            ' Wait until the buffer is empty
        Loop Until MSComm1.OutBufferCount = 0
    Loop

    ' close file
    Close #2

End Function
```

Comment: What kind of problems are you seeing?

Comment: i dont know on how to see if my command was actioned... because my app times out when i run send file function

Comment: What happens if you add a `DoEvents` inside your `Loop Until MSComm1.OutBufferCount=0`?

Comment: I still have outbufferCount returning 0 within the loop and an infinite loop

Comment: Could the infinite loop be that `EOF(2)` is always false?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the RThreshold and SThreshold properties

Below is a simple example project :

```
'1 form with :
'  1 label control   : name=Label1
'  1 textbox control : name=Text1
'  1 command button  : name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  'send command
  MSComm1.Output = Text1.Text & vbCr
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  'config mscomm control and open connection
  With MSComm1
    .Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
    .RThreshold = 1
    .SThreshold = 0
    .CommPort = 1
    .PortOpen = True
  End With 'MSComm1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  'position controls
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  Dim sngCmdWidth As Single, sngCmdHeight As Single
  Dim sngTxtWidth As Single
  Dim sngLblHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight
  sngCmdWidth = 1215
  sngCmdHeight = 495
  sngLblHeight = sngHeight - sngCmdHeight
  sngTxtWidth = sngWidth - sngCmdWidth
  Label1.Move 0, 0, sngWidth, sngLblHeight
  Text1.Move 0, sngLblHeight, sngTxtWidth, sngCmdHeight
  Command1.Move sngTxtWidth, sngLblHeight, sngCmdWidth, sngCmdHeight
End Sub

Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
  'process received data
  Dim strInput As String
  Select Case MSComm1.CommEvent
    Case comEvReceive
      strInput = MSComm1.Input
      Label1.Caption = Label1.Caption & strInput
  End Select
End Sub
```

In Command1_Click I add a carriage return to the command from Text1 as most devices require the command to be finished by that

In MSComm1_OnComm I just print the received data to the label, but you might want to add the received data to a global variable, and then process the contents of that variable, as all data might not be received at once

Comment: I have tried adding ".Settings = "9600,N,8,1"    .RThreshold = 1     .SThreshold = 0" and i think some data was being sent over. What I have noticed is that my screen froze and after about 5-10min nothing happened and i have stopped the application

Comment: that has nothing to do with the communication, but is caused by a tight loop in your code ... i suggest you make a new project with just the code of above, and build from there .... try to use no loops at first and see if that works .. then start adding the loops

Comment: also try to add some DoEvents inside your loops, and show the progress of the loop somewhere (for example by printing a counter value to the caption of your form), so you can see wether the loop is still running or not